# Saving Large json data mongodb

Tags: node.js, json, database, mongodb, mongoose

In my application I use mongoose for working with MongoDB. In my node server I have a request to third party API to get flight data. The size of returning data of this API can be more than 30mb. For now I'm trying to save it in one field and mongo doesn't allow to do it because of exceeding limit. I was thinking of saving it field by field in different document, but there are really a lot of amount fields and some of them can be changed because it is third party API.

I would be very appreciate if someone could tell: What are the possible ways to save this data in Mongo?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a specification I found in Mongo that calls [GridJS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/). Seems like it is what needs to store such data in one field.